# Debugging and debugging tools in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I've just started using Elixir, and have started a Phoenix project, which I enjoy a lot.
Now by having rails background, I'm used to being spoiled with debugging tools like "debugger", "byebug" and so on; I was wondering if there are any similar tools for Elixir? How are you guys debugging your Elixir applications?

Even an equivalent to Rubys `raise my_object.inspect`, would do wonders!

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at this awesome list, mentioning some debugging tools: https://github.com/h4cc/awesome-elixir#debugging

Comment: For what it's worth, I've heard that this book: http://www.erlang-in-anger.com/ has some awesome advice on debugging Erlang.  Most of the tools one would use with Erlang are equally applicable to Elixir.

Comment: Not 100% related but it is also worth mentioning `:observer.start` (run it on IEx). It is a great tool for debugging and exploring running applications.

Comment: Any thoughts about debugging Phoenix/cowboy apps, say if you want to debug the behavior of a controller when a request rolls in.

Comment: Old thread but you should check this out if you haven't yet https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pj6zAgvVt5w

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use `IEx`

```
require IEx

value = {:some, :erlang, :value}
IEx.pry
```

If you start this program with for example `iex -s program.exs` (or `iex -S mix` for a project) you'll be asked if you want to allow prying into this code when it is reached and `value` will be available for you for inspection.

You can also just do print debugging using `IO.inspect` allowing you to output basically any erlang data structure.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that IO.inspect returns the given argument. So if you have a code like `foo(bar, baz)`, you can directly add `foo(IO.inspect(bar), baz)` and everything will behave the same.

Comment: Does this work in phoenix? I get a server crash when I try it.

Comment: for windows you want to use `iex.bat --werl -S mix phoenix.server`

Comment: I hope a link to [IEx.pry/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/iex/IEx.html#pry/1) documentation would be useful

Comment: For further reading, the official website also has some detailed information about: it https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/debugging.html

Answer (score 33):

**Debugging Cowboy apps, and Phoenix apps.**

I saw this post in the Elixir rader http://www.jessetrimble.net/iex-pry-elixir, and thought i would just summarise it up here, as it's extremely convenient :-).

In Rails applications (and other), you can simply put in the debugger tag in your controller, and when the path is triggered, it will break at the debugger tag.

When using pry in Phoenix the above will result in

```
Cannot pry #PID<0.259.0> at web/controllers/posts_controller.ex:8. Is an IEx shell running?
```

It turns out that the Phoenix process must run within an IEx session, this is done as such

```
iex -S mix phoenix.server
```

Now instead you will see

```
Request to pry #PID<0.266.0> at web/controllers/posts_controller.ex:9. Allow? [Yn]
```

Comment: I think the mix task `phoenix.start` has been replaced for `phoenix.server`

Comment: I'm new to Elixir and Phoenix so this could be a dump question. In understand that with pry I can inspect the variables and (being into iex) I can make function calls. But this is only half of a debugger's functionality:  how can I follow the execution flow of the program? Is there another tool to let me advance to the next line and step into functions? Ruby's byebug has both functionalities.

Comment: If you're using Docker to run your Phoenix app, this won't work.

Answer (score 11):

You can use  `Quaff.Debug` module from https://github.com/qhool/quaff

> The Debug module provides a simple helper interface for running Elixir
>   code in the erlang graphical debugger

I tested it today with Elixir 1.0.4, it works.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Erlang debugger. 
Example with Phoenix 1.3 and Elixir 1.5.1, source file: ./lib/todo/api/api.ex and the module name is: Todo.API

```
~/elixir/todo_app/ iex -S mix phx.server
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0] [source] [smp:1:1] [ds:1:1:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

[info] Running TodoWeb.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://0.0.0.0:4000
Interactive Elixir (1.5.1) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> :debugger.start()
{:ok, #PID<0.373.0>}
iex(2)> :int.ni(Todo.API)
{:module, Todo.API}
```

In the Erlang debugger:

- The left panel in the Monitor window shows the loaded module.
- The Module menu, the bottom item shows the loaded module with a 'View' and 'Delete' submenu. Use the View menu to see the source with line numbers.
- To place a breakpoint, use the Break menu, Line breaks...
- Run your program until it stops at the specified line. The Monitor windows shows a process with status 'break'. Double click on this line to open the attached process in the debugger. Here you can step, step over (next), continue, go up, inspect values, etc. To step into another module it must be loaded like above as well.
- A breakpoint will be ignored if not correctly placed. If you have a multiline pipeline, place the breakpoint on the last line.

Answer (score 1):

In Elixir 1.5 and OTP 20 there's a new function `Exception.blame/3` which can add debug information to certain exceptions. It only supports `FunctionClauseErrors` right now and you should only use it in development because it's an expensive task: the function will retrieve the available clauses from bytecode and evaluate them against the given arguments. [See Release](https://elixir-lang.org/blog/2017/07/25/elixir-v1-5-0-released/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to debug tests similar to byebug does: Using the command `iex -S mix test`, this will run your tests and if an `IEx.pry` was encountered, it will ask if you want to "stop" there and analyze its context.

Code example:

```
defmodule AppTest do
  def hello do
    test_variable = "john doe"
    require IEx; IEx.pry
    :world
  end
end
```

```
defmodule AppTestTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  doctest AppTest

  test "greets the world" do
    assert AppTest.hello() == :world
  end
end
```

Running `iex -S mix test` it will stop in the `require IEx; IEx.pry`.

Source: https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-debug-exunit-tests-with-debugger/14170/4